# The model is sorting the items by id not alphabetically

Tags: python, django

I have a main model called `Produto`. On this model, the items shows up like they have, alphabetically(see below).

Also I have another one, called `EstoqueSede`, that has a `FK` to the `Produto` model(It's a stock application, so i have a product `Produto` model to register the items separated to the stock and two another stock models to hold the current amounts and some other values(of the mainstock and the substocks), because i have two stocks that access the product model `Produto` and this two models are not showing alphabetically(see below either), just the main model `Produto`.

Like i said, when a try to query the Produto model, the items shows as the intention, but when i show the `EstoqueSede` model items, instead of show the items alphabetically as the `Produto` model, it shows the items in the order that it was created in the database `MySql`, but actually, is ordering by the `ID's` of the `EstoqueSede` model...

When i override the `get_queryset(self, obj)` on Admin of the EstoqueSede, i could get those values alphabetically when i click in the model(see also below), but when i want to order the items within the model, with the `/?=0` or `/?=-0` url(or clicking on the field name to order), the items have their behaviors changed to the original state and the order goes off. It sorts asc and desc ID order, but not alphabetically.

My Produto model:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY9mp.png

My EstoqueSede model without the order:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4Y75.png

My EstoqueSede model with the order:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLGlL.png

My `Produto` script model:

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from estoque.models.categoria import *
from usuarios.models import Usuario

class Produto(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField('nome do produto', max_length=145, unique=True)
    cat = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='categoria_id', verbose_name='categoria')
    estoque_minimo = models.IntegerField('estoque mínimo na sede', default = 10)
    estoque_min_unidades = models.IntegerField('estoque mínimo nos polos', default = 10)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='produto cadastrado por')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'estoque'
        db_table = 'est_produto'
        verbose_name = u'produto cadastrado'
        verbose_name_plural = u'produtos Cadastrados'

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.descricao)
```

My `EstoqueSede` script model:

```
#-*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from django.db import models
from estoque.models.categoria import *
from estoque.models.produtos import Produto

class EstoqueSede(models.Model):
    produto = models.ForeignKey(
        Produto, 
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name = 'produto'
    )
    quantidade = models.IntegerField(
        default = 0,
    )

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'estoque'
        db_table = 'est_estoque_sede'
        verbose_name = u'estoque da Sede'
        verbose_name_plural = u'estoque da Sede'

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.produto.descricao)
```

And the `EstoqueSede` `Admin`:

```
class EstoqueSedeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ProdutosForm
    model = EstoqueSede
    change_list_template = 'admin/lista.html'
    list_display = ('produto','quantidade_override','estoque_minimo',)
    list_filter = ('produto__descricao',)
    list_display_links = ('produto',)
    inlines = [ViewEstoqueSedeEntradasInline, ViewEstoqueSedeSaidasInline]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(EstoqueSedeAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        qs = qs.order_by('produto__descricao')
        return qs

    @mark_safe
    def estoque_minimo(self, obj):
        return Produto.objects.get(id=obj.produto.pk).estoque_minimo

    @mark_safe
    def quantidade_override(self, obj):
        return get_color_format_ammount(self, obj, True)

    quantidade_override.short_description = 'quantidade'

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

admin.site.register(Produto, ProdutosAdmin)
admin.site.register(EstoqueSede, EstoqueSedeAdmin)
```

I am very new on the django and also python(a month to be sure), but I'm a developer on others IDE's and languages by a few years ago and I realized a lot of things that i could interpret, search and apply in the app, but not this 'simple' thing(i think, and probably it's not). I'm looking for an approach on this a few days ago, but i just can't find any solutions. Taking a look on this, it seems like foolish, because it's just aesthetic thing, but this is from my work and I want to do the best. Everyone is good but sometimes we need to be 'perfect'.
Thank you all, sorry for my bad english, and i hope me and you all have a nice week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin has a specific property to specify ordering calling `ordering` [1]. You don't need to override the queryset, instead set

```
class EstoqueSedeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    ordering = ["produto__descricao"]
```

By default the admin applies the default model ordering to its queryset, so overriding `get_queryset` does not change the ordering results.

EDIT:

I now understand that it's the ordering when clicking on the sort header in the `list_display` in the admin. From what I can tell for that you need to override the `get_ordering_field` for that field in the `ChangeList` view used to render the changelist.

```
class EstoqueSedeChangeList(admin.views.main.ChangeList):
   def get_ordering_field(self, field_name):
        if field_name == "produto":
            return "produto__descricao"
        return super().get_ordering_field(field_name)

class EstoqueSedeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_changelist(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return EstoqueSedeChangeList
```

EDIT 2

A simpler way to achieve this is to use an admin method as your `list_display` field with a `admin_order_field` attribute:

```
class EstoqueSedeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    list_display = ('produto_descricao','quantidade_override','estoque_minimo',)
    ...

    def produto_descricao(self, obj):
        return obj.produto.descricao

    produto_descricao.admin_order_field = 'produto__descricao'
```

[1] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.ordering

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, but I had already tried that and unfortunately to me, it does not affect anything when i put the ```ordering = ['produto__descricao]``` tuple, list or just ```produto```... I tried overriding the ```get_ordering(request)``` either, but also did not work

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't understand that you weren't just looking at default ordering but rather when you click the sort buttons in the admin, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear, but now this, edit 2 worked like a charm... I did not know that would be this simples, thanks man!!!

Comment: Great! Was an interesting question, haven't come across that situation before and there wasn't very clear documentation so I learned a bunch looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

In your EstoqueSede model Meta class use [order-with-respect-to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to) to specify the ordering of the model based on it's relationship to another Model.

```
class Meta:
    order_with_respect_to = 'Produto'
```

Although this allows you to specify the ordering of the `EstoqueSede` it might only be possible to use it's primary key...

Comment: Yes, with this i would have to add another column in the DB, called order, but thanks for the help!!